# What is the meaning of "capoon cutcheny"?

Tags: meaning, chinese

While researching the Treaty of Wanghia between the US and China, I saw the Product "capoon cutcheny" in the drugs section of the tariff table. Since I am neither an English nor a Chinese native speaker, I thought googling might help. Interestingly, the exact term only appeared five times, all either this treaty or in reference to it. By researching both words I found that "capoon" means castrated rooster, but I did not find any reference to "cutcheny" other than in this Treaty or as a last name. Does anybody have any idea what it means?

Comment: Of note: *capoon* occurs precisely once in OED (in a quote as a 15th-century term for *capon*) and *cutcheny* not at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am reasonably certain this is a transcription error, and given the context of drugs, that the actual entry is *capoor cutchery*. [According to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capoor%20cutchery), this is

> the dried root of an East Indian plant (*Hedychium spicatum*)

which is [elsewhere cited as](https://books.google.com/books?id=3jZBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA191) "a fragrant root… said to come from India." Note that the Chinese characters in the sources (三奈, 山奈) may refer to a different plant, perhaps *Kaempferia galanga* or *Curcuma zedoaria*. My knowledge of botany, TCM, or Chinese characters is slim to say the least, so I make no pronouncements as to which is species is canonical.

The text of the treaty as printed in *[Treaties and conventions Concluded Between the United States of America and Other Powers Since July
4, 1776](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/217226209.pdf)*, an 1871 report from the Secretary of State to the U.S. Senate, gives the tariff table entry as *capoor cutchery* (page 140), and this product being of commercial value and medicinal use is attested in *[A Chinese Commercial Guide](https://library.um.edu.mo/ebooks/b25884761.pdf)* by S. Wells Williams, in the fourth edition (1858) of which is given this description:

> 11. Capoor cutchery, son lai, the Indian name means
>     root of camphor. This is the root of a tuberous plant which grows
>     in Fuhkien and Sr'chuen ; it is half an inch and more in diameter,
>     and is cut into small pieces and dried for exportation; the cleavage
>     is covered with a fine reddish pellicle, but externally it is rough and
>     of a reddish color. It is powdered and mixed with oil, and thus employed in friction and plasters; it has a pungent and bitterish taste,
>     and a slight aromatic smell. It is exported in small amounts to
>     Bombay, and from thence to Persia and Arabia, where it is used in
>     perfumery and for medicinal purposes, and also to preserve clothes
>     from insects.

You can find it under various spellings (*capour*, *capor*, *kapoor*) in various trade gazettes, tariff tables, and similar government and commercial documents.

Comment: Does it do any medical things that would corroborate it being in the drug section of the treaty?

Comment: Antihelmintic or antihelminthic? One may contain heroin.

Comment: Good idea.  Under OCR, *r* comes out *n*.

Comment: @Mitch, it was/is used throughout Asia as an antihelmintic (treatment for parasites such as worms) and in medicines, food, cosmetics and perfumery industries. Traditionally, it is widely used in treating inflammation, pain, asthma, foul breath, vomiting, diarrhoea, bronchitis, hiccough and blood diseases. Had a value of about $6 per pecul dockside at Canton in 1839. Grown in China and exported to various countries including Persia and Arabia. A pecul or picul was a Chinese measure of weight equal to roughly 133 pounds or 60 kg.

Comment: I could not find the original source, but this https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hncv31&view=1up&seq=3&skin=2021 copy of a Havard Library copy from 1952 clearly says "capoon", although that may have been a typo that was simply copied over and over again.

Comment: It seems to be a source of camphor: https://useful_english.en-academic.com/178591/capoor_cutchery -- **capoor cutchery** \kə|pu̇(ə)rˈkəchərē\ noun -- Etymology: Hindi kapūr-kacarī, from kapūr camphor (from Sanskrit karpūra) + kacarī (Hedychium spicatum) — more at camphor: the dried root of an East Indian plant (Hedychium spicatum)

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=G3s4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=capoon+cutcheny&source=bl&ots=3j9ukNRxRu&sig=ACfU3U1EHGwmshk4BVAZKKCnYkiCDUQkZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6jbjs0832AhUkkYkEHba1BB4Q6AF6BAgTEAM#v=onepage&q=capoon%20cutcheny&f=false

Comment: @Lambie [capoon cutcheny](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=capoon+cutcheny) five results. [capoor cutchery](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&gl=en&q=capoor+cutchery) pages and pages of [results](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Quarterly_Trade_Returns/gyZBAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=capoor+cutchery&pg=PA88&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @ColleenV I don't care much about the spelling. I care about showing it is a product in a list of products and that this spelling was in an official document produced in the States back in the 1800's.

Comment: @Lambie Well, that would have been a helpful thing to add to your comment instead of posting a bare link. Most of us can't read minds over the Internet. ;)